# JDK 9: JUnit 5 test compile with SpringExtension produces java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ls/DocumentLS

Tags: spring-test, java-9, junit5

I believe this problem not to be related to module exclusions in JDK 9 (as with java.se.ee), but rather with the fact that JDK 9 includes a newer version of [org.w3c.dom.ls](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ls/package-summary.html) in the [java.xml](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java.xml-summary.html) module that does not have the DocumentLS class.

The important bit of the stack trace is this:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [spring-test/test-container.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ls/DocumentLS
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
```

Even if I include a runtime dependency with this class, like `xerces:xerces 2.4.0`, the JDK java.xml module is preferred (I guess).

I am using Gradle 4.1. Is there any way to restrict the scope of a 
JDK provided module?

Answer (score 4):

As you have correctly analyzed, the package `org.w3c.dom.ls` is present in [the platform module *java.xml*](http://download.java.net/java/jigsaw/docs/api/java.xml-summary.html). Any class on the class path that is in the same package will be ignored. That's called [a *split package*](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-9-migration-guide/#Split-Packages) and [several fixes](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-9-migration-guide/#fixes-2) exist - the following two might help you.

### Patch *java.xml*

You can add the classes of the Xerxes JAR to the *java.xml* module with [`--patch-module`](https://blog.codefx.org/java/five-command-line-options-to-hack-the-java-9-module-system/#Adding-Classes-To-Modules-With--patch-module):

```
java --patch-module java.xml=xerxes-4.0.0.jar ...
```

I've never tried that with a JAR that contains some of the same classes. As I understand it, the JDK classes will then be replaced with the Xerxes classes, which means they better be a fully binary compatible replacement.

### Upgrade *java.xml*

Another hope is to replace *java.xml* with the [upgrade module path](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261#Module-paths):

> The upgrade module path (`--upgrade-module-path`) contains compiled definitions of modules intended to be used in place of upgradeable modules built-in to the environment (compile time and run time).

You face two problems:

- the upgrade module path is supposed to be used only for upgradable modules (which *java.xml* is not), but I think I've read somewhere that that's not enforced (yet?) - didn't try it
- the artifact you replace *java.xml* with needs to be fully binary compatible update - would that be the case for Xerxes?

Comment: Thanks for the insight and documentation references.  I have now noticed that the class missing failure appears on runtime and not at compile time.  Why does not the compiler not report "split package" issues at compile time?  I guess that this DocumentLS class is a transitive runtime dependency of spring-core.  I would rather opt to address the problem downstream as hacking the JDK, while interesting, is probably not portable.

Comment: Also, I have tried to get more info about how the launcher resolves the split package with the -Xdiag:resolver option, but IntelliJ does not allow me to  pass it as a Gradle VM runtime option...

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell, DocumentLS is from a 2002 draft of the W3C API, it doesn't appear to have made it into a released version. It looks like xerces-2.4.0 (from 2006?) includes it but newer versions don't. So upgrading  to a more recent Xerces may be needed here. If Spring really depends on DocumentLS then it will need to be updated too.