# Exception in thread "main" quickfix.ConfigError: FIX44.xml: Could not parse data dictionary file

Tags: automated-tests, fix-protocol

I am able to run fix with UseDataDictionary=N but when I turn this into UseDataDictionary=Y

FIX44.xml: Could not parse data dictionary file

Someone please help me what is wrong.

```
Caused by: quickfix.ConfigError: Could not parse data dictionary file
at quickfix.DataDictionary.load(DataDictionary.java:857)
at quickfix.DataDictionary.read(DataDictionary.java:838)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ls/DocumentLS

    [DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
HeartBtInt=60
ReconnectInterval=1
FileStorePath=.\fixfiles\initiator
FileLogPath=.\log
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
UseDataDictionary=Y
DataDictionary=FIX44.xml
SocketReuseAddress=Y
SocketKeepAlive=Y
SocketTcpNoDelay=Y
ResetOnLogon=Y
```

Comment: Are you running with a JDK9 or higher? Could you try adding `--add-modules java.se.ee` as arguments. Maybe this does also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723488/jdk-9-junit-5-test-compile-with-springextension-produces-java-lang-noclassdeffo

Comment: I am compiling with Java 8 and still keep getting error.

Comment: Compilation does not matter in this case. With which JRE or JDK do you run it?

Answer (score 0):

Well the QF library is saying that it can load the DD but not parse it, therefore your DD is corrupt. I would recommend looking at the default DD that comes with the install pack.

Comment: There is a `NoClassDefFoundError`. This clearly has nothing to do with the DD itself.

Comment: I see, so it has the classes to load but not parse the dictionary. ok...